# Where do I find full details of librairies for the processing programming language

Tags: class, processing, information-retrieval

I am using `processing` to read serial data from a USB port, and in all the examples the port is opened with:

```
myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[4], 4800);
```

To fully understand this I looked for details of the parameters in this call of the `Serial` class but the official reference in [processing.org](http://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial.html) does not mention the parameters at all, not even how many, and I now know that there could be up to six.

After a lot of searching I did find the details in [this reference](http://www.technotype.net/processing/reference/libraries/serial/Serial.html), which appears to be an older version, and is a much fuller and complete description. I am surprised that I did not find it via the `processing.org` website, and that so much detail has been omitted in the current version.

My question is: please where *should* I have looked for the official processing library definitions that *do* give all the details. Or have I missed something obvious to everyone but me?

Irrelevant background: I am reading data from a small GPS receiver module. There is a lot of fascinating stuff in the data which I want to process and display in various graphical ways, and `processing` is brilliant for doing that sort of thing. I expect to need more libraries and will need their details, too, so this question is important to me.

---

Added following the comment from Colonel Thirty Two. Thanks for the new reference, it is certainly comprehensive.

Comment: The header is `public Serial(PApplet parent, String portName, int baudRate, char parity, int dataBits, float stopBits)` found from here: https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/java/libraries/serial/src/processing/serial/Serial.java

Comment: @HarryWeston To add to Colonel Thirty Two's comment, here is the [documentation for Processing's Serial library](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/). You can find other Processing libraries [here](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/) and notice the ones that ship with Processing (DXF,Serial,Video,etc.) are at the top

Comment: Thank you George Profenza. The reference you give is the one that has the example I quoted, which works, but gives no details of the parameters, which is what prompted my question